# PHP: Updating localhost sql file on remote server using curl

Tags: php

Request Entity Too Large
The requested resource
/receive.php
does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

---

The above is the error I got from CURL-based database update . The online updating process work fine when the SQL file size below 700kb. But it fails to update when the SQL file grew above  1MB. I know it requires a particular setting somewhere which I don't have any idea. I have worked on the PHP ini but its not working. Please help me out

---

```
  ?php
  //for localhost: export.php
  //$location is the complete exported sql file location on the local system.

    $data=file_get_contents($location);

    $url="www.mysite.com/receive.php";
    $ch= curl_init();
    $data ="sql=". $data;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $feedback = curl_exec($ch);
    ?>

    <?php
    // for remote server: receive.php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'username';
    $dbpass = 'password';
    $dbname = 'databasename';

   if(isset($_REQUEST['sql'])):
   $link = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
   mysql_select_db($dbname,$link);

   $post=$_REQUEST);
   foreach($data as $record)
   {
   $record = ($record);
   try{mysql_query($record);}catch(Exception $e){}
   }

   echo "<h1><font color='green'>Update Of Online Database And Back Up     Successfully Done</font></h1>";
 else:
  echo "<h1><font color='red'>Data Update Failed</font></h1>";
  endif;
  $time=date("h:a:i:s");
  $day=date("Y-m-d");
  $ti=$day." / ".$time;
   mysql_query("UPDATE last_update_tb SET update_data='$ti'")or   die(mysql_error());
 ?>
```